# GAM + Prebid - Ads load slowly

Tags: google-ad-manager, prebid.js, prebid

The lower-level ads in the article load slowly. This is probably because I have lazy bidding on for BTF AdUnits.

How do you get it resolved?

Immediately when the page loads, do you send a prebid request for all AdUnits that are on the page or do you use some kind of lazy bidding?

Comment: do you use lazy loading ? are you in a Single Request Architecture ? could you share a code sample ?

Comment: define "slowly" please